# GeoNode credentials not valid for OGC services

Tags: geonode, ows, geoserver-geofence

I have GeoNode 2.6.3 installed in ubuntu 16.04 server [(standard instalation)](http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/install_and_admin/geonode_install/index.html). The web portal works fine with authentications, view and download permissons, etc. But when i try to access via WFS/WMS services on QGis, Geonode credetials are not valid. I can access with no credentials and see the public layers, and i can access using the geoserver credentials, but not with geonode ones (tried with diferent users).
geoserver.log file shows:

```
2017-11-13 12:14:47,164 WARN [geofence.cache] - org.geoserver.geofence.cache.CachedRuleReader$NoAuthException: Can't auth user [gpadmin]
```

(gpadmin is the geonode admin username)

Geofence configuration is as default, and not service security rules added. I can access geoserver adminUI with geonode credentials.
I´ve read [this link](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/auth/owsrest.html) too but can´t figure out the problem.

Any ideas or tips to find the problem?

Comment: I am with similar problem which I have described <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63632123/layer-not-shown-in-geonode>.

If you got answer to your problem, I would request you to suggest me the solution.

Thank You.